# How to plot the elevation from a digital elevation model in R?

Tags: r, r-sf

## Data

I have southern Ontario DEM stored as a `.gdb` database. I found the following info. in the technical specifications manual:

[image]

### Getting data in R

```
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)


fgdb <- "ogde_south_dem/ProvincialDEM_South.gdb"

all_layers <- st_layers(dsn = fgdb)

> all_layers
Driver: OpenFileGDB 
Available layers:
            layer_name     geometry_type features fields
1               dem068     Multi Polygon        1      3
2               dem069     Multi Polygon        1      3
3               dem070     Multi Polygon        1      3
4               dem071     Multi Polygon        1      3
5               dem072     Multi Polygon        1      3
6               dem073     Multi Polygon        1      3
7               dem074     Multi Polygon        1      3
8               dem075     Multi Polygon        1      3
9               dem076     Multi Polygon        1      3
10              dem077     Multi Polygon        1      3
11              dem078     Multi Polygon        1      3
12              dem079     Multi Polygon        1      3
13              dem080     Multi Polygon        1      3
14              dem081     Multi Polygon        1      3
15              dem083     Multi Polygon        1      3
16              dem084     Multi Polygon        1      3
17              dem085     Multi Polygon        1      3
18              dem086     Multi Polygon        1      3
19              dem087     Multi Polygon        1      3
20              dem090     Multi Polygon        1      3
21              dem091     Multi Polygon        1      3
22              dem092     Multi Polygon        1      3
23              dem093     Multi Polygon        1      3
24              dem094     Multi Polygon        1      3
25              dem096     Multi Polygon        1      3
26              dem097     Multi Polygon        1      3
27              dem098     Multi Polygon        1      3
28              dem099     Multi Polygon        1      3
29              dem100     Multi Polygon        1      3
30              dem101     Multi Polygon        1      3
31              dem102     Multi Polygon        1      3
32              dem103     Multi Polygon        1      3
33              dem104     Multi Polygon        1      3
34              dem105     Multi Polygon        1      3
35              dem106     Multi Polygon        1      3
36              dem107     Multi Polygon        1      3
37              dem108     Multi Polygon        1      3
38              dem110     Multi Polygon        1      3
39              dem111     Multi Polygon        1      3
40              dem112     Multi Polygon        1      3
41              dem113     Multi Polygon        1      3
42              dem114     Multi Polygon        1      3
43              dem115     Multi Polygon        1      3
44              dem117     Multi Polygon        1      3
45              dem118     Multi Polygon        1      3
46              dem119     Multi Polygon        1      3
47              dem120     Multi Polygon        1      3
48              dem121     Multi Polygon        1      3
49              dem122     Multi Polygon        1      3
50              dem123     Multi Polygon        1      3
51              dem124     Multi Polygon        1      3
52              dem127     Multi Polygon        1      3
53              dem128     Multi Polygon        1      3
54              dem129     Multi Polygon        1      3
55              dem130     Multi Polygon        1      3
56              dem131     Multi Polygon        1      3
57              dem088     Multi Polygon        1      3
58              dem126     Multi Polygon        1      3
59      MosaicBoundary Multi Line String      143      3
60     ElevationSource     Multi Polygon       13      3
61 ProvincialDEM_Index     Multi Polygon      126      4
62 OBM_PhotoBlockIndex     Multi Polygon       23      8
63              dem082     Multi Polygon        1      3
```

Reading a single layer:

```
> df <- sf::st_read(dsn=fgdb, layer = "dem126")
Reading layer `dem126' from data source `C:\Users\path\to\ogde_south_dem\ProvincialDEM_South.gdb' using driver `OpenFileGDB'
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 3 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 1113210 ymin: 11760000 xmax: 1140030 ymax: 11819820
projected CRS:  NAD_1983_Lambert_Conformal_Conic
```

### Plotting

> Objective: I want to plot the elevation of southern Ontario.

#### Problem:

When I try to use `plot` or `geom_sf` I only see rectangles.

```
plot(df)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

### Question

How do I plot all the `dem` layers so that color shows the **elevation** in all tiles?

Comment: Any chance you can link the data?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share it because it is obtained from the university library.

Comment: I can't figure out this one without the data, but there is elevation data for south Ontario from https://geohub.lio.gov.on.ca/.  A tif file from there can be read using `raster` and the plot should look like: http://mrhellmann.com/south_ontario.png